# Printing derived object using operator<< overload not working

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

Why can I not print the derived object using this approach?  How can I fix this so that the derived printout prints "derived size=8".  I ideally want to keep the printing code out of the class code.

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
public:
   base(int size) : size_(size) {}

   virtual int get_size() const { return size_; }

private:
   int size_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const base& obj) {
   os << "base size=" << obj.get_size() << std::endl;
   return os;
}

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
   derived1(int size) : base(size) {}

   virtual int get_size() const { 
      return 2 * base::get_size();
   }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const derived1& obj) {
   os << "derived1 size=" << obj.get_size() << std::endl;
   return os;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   base* b1 = new base(3);
   std::cout << "b1 size is: " << b1->get_size() << std::endl;

   std::cout << *b1 << std::endl;

   base* b2 = new derived1(4);
   std::cout << "b2 size is: " << b2->get_size() << std::endl;

   std::cout << *b2 << std::endl;

   delete b1;
   delete b2;
   return 0;
}

Output:
b1 size is: 3
base size=3

b2 size is: 8
base size=8
```

UPDATE:

I changed as follows as per ghostsofstandardspast which works:

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
public:
   base(int size) : size_(size) {}

   virtual int get_size() const { return size_; }
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const base& obj);

private:
   virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os) const {
      return os << "base size=" << get_size() << std::endl;
   }

   int size_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const base& obj) {
   obj.print(os);
   return os;
}

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
   derived1(int size) : base(size) {}

   virtual int get_size() const { 
      return 2 * base::get_size();
   }

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const derived1& obj);
private:
   virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os) const {
      return os << "derived1 size=" << get_size() << std::endl;
   }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   base* b1 = new base(3);
   std::cout << "b1 size is: " << b1->get_size() << std::endl;

   std::cout << *b1 << std::endl;

   base* b2 = new derived1(4);
   std::cout << "b2 size is: " << b2->get_size() << std::endl;

   std::cout << *b2 << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need dynamic dispatch, so you need a virtual method.

Comment: Instead of `x->get_size()` do `*x`.

Comment: It might help if you said what output you currently get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator<<` is not a virtual member function, so it can't be used polymorphically like other member functions can. Instead, you should delegate to a virtual member.

Change both of your `operator<<` overloads to a virtual member function called `print` or something similar. Then, overload `operator<<` to delegate to that:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Base &obj) {
    obj.print(os); //or whatever name you choose
    return os;
}
```

If you want to make the member function private, make `operator<<` a friend.

Finally, note that printing a pointer to an object of your class will only print the address. To invoke `operator<<`, you need to print the object itself:

```
Base *b = /*whatever*/;
std::cout << *b;
```

---

This technique for a polymorphic `operator<<` is demonstrated in [this cppquiz question](http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/27). I highly recommend going through those questions.

Answer (score 0):

`cout << b2` doesn't invoke your operator <<, because `b2` is a pointer not a reference. Try `cout << *b2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because in a call

```
std::cout << b1 << std::endl;
```

you are printing an address, since `b1` is a pointer ( i.e. 0x8e02008).

You should dereference it instead

```
std::cout << *b1 << std::endl;
```

In this case both for `*b1` and `*b2` objects the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const base& obj);` will be calles and virtual call to `get_size()` will be executed.

[ideone](http://ideone.com/P1peED)

Comment: I was playing and forgot to put back dereference - sorry about that.  But main problem is get printing as if b2 was base.